# How to assign an string[] to a const without undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have a question which I don't seem to understand.
I want to assign a `string[]` to this the `const categoryNames`

```
const categories = ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3'];
const dataMap: Map<string, string> = new Map([
    ['cat1','Dogs'],
    ['cat2','Cats'],
]);

const catNames = categories
        .filter((id) => dataMap.has(id))
        .map((id) => dataMap.get(id));

const categoryNames: string[] = catNames === undefined ? [] : catNames;
```

I get this error however

> TS2322: Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type
> 'string[]'.

But I don't understand why? I am clearly asking, if `catNames` is undefined, the give me just an `empty array`, and if it's not, give me `catNames`

I need the categoryNames to be strictly `string[]`, and not `string[] | undefined`

How can this work?

Comment: try `const categoryNames: string[] = catNames || []`  OR `const categoryNames: string[] = catNames ?? []`

Comment: The same error remains, tried both ?? and ||

Comment: Are you sure `catNames` will always be undefined? If so, use `catNames!`, which tells TypeScript it will never be undefined.

Comment: Typescript compiler is performing strict null checks. Take a look at `Non-null assertion operator` => `https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator`

Comment: @Heretic Monkey. You mean `const categoryNames: string[] = catNames!`

Comment: @NavnathJadhav Obviously. Wouldn't work anywhere else...

Comment: @NavnathJadhav Still the same error, and an ESLint error too "forbidden null assertion", but either way the original error remains

Comment: Can you share some `categoriesDataDoc` and `itemSummary` sample data. So that we can figure out at our side?

Comment: `let categoryNames: string[] = [];                                                                                                     
 if (catNames!=undefined) {
    categoryNames = catNames;
}`

Comment: @NavnathJadhav I updated the question with copy/paste testable in tsplayground. Correction, it still doesnt work even with the if statement

Comment: What is your TS version?

Comment: The latest stable, 4.4.2, look https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=38#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGUCmBzEAnAlkiMC8MA2gOQJQCMxANDKYgEzW1kDMxAugNwBQoksAE0TwAsvAAOALhhjxAHmhYwKGoszKAfPhhgkAdxkSAFIW4xzROhWrEAIiBQQOVMxZJlGVYgGFET9i7sAJQ83AA2SLBkqBgAngBy8AC2ONJqyoTsBJk8fNBwiIkpuATRaFg4rhYWAHQAZphhyOhGRpgCQfhaQlCiEjUAFvAQbR1BVdUwNUnGo5143cKyNSiRcyHc3Jh1RmRFODAAhHgEAK5gAkgNuh0wAN4TZXH7JQVQLzwAvtxAA

Comment: `(string | undefined)[]` is not the same as `string[] | undefined`. The problem is that (Typescript believes) your array can contain the value `undefined`, not that the array itself could be `undefined`.

Comment: Right. That was the issue while getting the date from map `dataMap.get(id)`

Comment: what makes you think that `catNames` is `string[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error says :

`Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Its while getting result from  datamap by id which return string. We could do `dataMap.get(id)!` or `dataMap.get(id) || ''` to avoid `undefined`.

Since we are already using a filter and then getting items from the map, we are sure that result will be available. so i chose to use [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `(!)` operator

```
const catNames = categories
            .filter((id) => dataMap.has(id))
            .map((id) => dataMap.get(id)!);
    
   const categoryNames: string[] = catNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [code in Navatah answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69079567/3001856) is working. I would suggest using reversed order of `filter` and `map`.

```
const catNames = categories
  .map(id => dataMap.get(id)) // Get it, if it is not there return undefined
  .filter((data): data is string => !!data); // Remove undefined from array and type
    
const categoryNames: string[] = catNames;
```